# vb.net: column names using recordset as Odbc.OdbcDataReader

Tags: vb.net, postgresql

I'm creating a Web Service that retrive data from postgres DB.

Here my code:

```
    Dim sql As String
    Dim recordSet As Odbc.OdbcDataReader
    Dim command As Odbc.OdbcCommand
    Dim ret As New DataOutput
    Dim dataLst As New List(Of Data)
    Dim element As Dati

sql = "SELECT * from demo.table"
        command = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(sql, odbcConn)

        Try
            recordSet = command.ExecuteReader
            While recordSet.Read()
                element = New Data
                element.id = recordSet(0)
                element.name = recordSet(1)
                element.description = recordSet(2)
                element.address = recordSet(3)
                dataLst.Add(element)
            End While
        ret.arrDati = dataLst
```

This only show me rows value but I need column names too.
How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the column names with the [`GetName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.getname(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Dim sql As String
Dim recordSet As Odbc.OdbcDataReader
Dim command As Odbc.OdbcCommand
Dim ret As New DataOutput
Dim dataLst As New List(Of Data)
Dim element As Dati

sql = "SELECT * from demo.table"
command = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(sql, odbcConn)

Try
    recordSet = command.ExecuteReader

    While recordSet.Read()
        element = New Data
        element.id = recordSet(0)           'column name: recordSet.GetName(0)
        element.name = recordSet(1)         'column name: recordSet.GetName(1)
        element.description = recordSet(2)  'column name: recordSet.GetName(2)
        element.address = recordSet(3)      'column name: recordSet.GetName(3)
        dataLst.Add(element)
    End While

    ret.arrDati = dataLst
```